# Web service and global parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I start building a new web service  for my app and i want to make a global int for example that every time someone call this web service this int will increase in one.
this is what i create in visual studio:

```
    public partial class Form : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

and i try to put static int in the class but it not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your variable in Application state.

Note you need to make it thread safe.

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf(VS.80).aspx

```
Application.Lock();
Application["PageRequestCount"] = 
    ((int)Application["PageRequestCount"])+1;
Application.UnLock();
```